# Detect when wearable connected/disconnected to/from Android phone

Tags: android, events

The Pebble watch has a Intent that is globally sended when the Pebble is connected/disconnected. This allow the phone apps to know if the watch is connected or not.
I have searched but I'm not capable to locate info about a similar feature for Android Wear.
How know if a wearable is connected to the phone? Is possible to receive a event like with Pebble?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do this by extends the WearableListenerService and override onConnectedNodes() method.

**Wearable Side**

```
public class DisconnectListenerService extends WearableListenerService implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {

/* the capability that the phone app would provide */
private static final String CONNECTION_STATUS_CAPABILITY_NAME = "is_connection_lost";

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .build();
}

@Override
public void onConnectedNodes(List<Node> connectedNodes) {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        updateStatus();
    } else if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}

private void updateStatus() {
    Wearable.CapabilityApi.getCapability(
            mGoogleApiClient, CONNECTION_STATUS_CAPABILITY_NAME,
            CapabilityApi.FILTER_REACHABLE).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<CapabilityApi.GetCapabilityResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(CapabilityApi.GetCapabilityResult result) {
                    if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                        updateConnectionCapability(result.getCapability());
                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to get capabilities, " + "status: " + result.getStatus().getStatusMessage());
                    }
                }
            });
}

private void updateConnectionCapability(CapabilityInfo capabilityInfo) {
    Set<Node> connectedNodes = capabilityInfo.getNodes();
    if (connectedNodes.isEmpty()) {
        // The connection is lost !
    } else {
        for (Node node : connectedNodes) {
            if (node.isNearby()) {
                // The connection is OK !
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    updateStatus();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() || mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

**Phone Side**

create a xml file in values/ directory named wear.xml

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="android_wear_capabilities">
        <item>is_connection_lost</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

For more, checkout the my solution in this [Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26280830/android-wear-disconnection-notification/34540998#34540998)

Comment: This is not answer to the asked question ... should be flagged

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried [NodeApi](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/NodeApi.html#addListener(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20com.google.android.gms.wearable.NodeApi.NodeListener)), you can use `getConnectedNodes`

> Gets a list of Nodes to which this device is currently connected.

or `addListener(GoogleApiClient client, NodeApi.NodeListener listener)` which

> Registers a listener to receive all node events.

Then you can use callbacks from `NodeApi.NodeListener`

```
onPeerConnected(Node peer) and onPeerDisconnected(Node peer)
```

Answer (score 4):

As akmal said you can get devices which are connected to the phone, But to know whether the *wearable* currently connected with handheld

```
List<Node> connectedNodes =
    Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(mGoogleApiClient).await().getNodes();
```

The list contains data like this:

```
Node{Moto 360 6BBF, id=3b6d19bf, hops=1, isNearby=true}
```