# Android Wear disconnection notification

Tags: android, notifications

I have an Android Wear app which communicates accelerometer values to an Handheld app.

I want to be notified in the Handheld app when connection with the android wear app has just been lost (when the Android Wear app is closed, for instance).

How must I implement that ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Devices connected in the wear-to-device network are called Nodes. You can use the Node API to determine when devices enter or leave the network (e.g. when a wear device becomes disconnected from a phone).

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/NodeApi.NodeListener

You can also use the Node API to get a list of all connected devices (e.g all wear devices connected to a phone) at any given time

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/NodeApi

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this by extends the WearableListenerService and override onConnectedNodes() method.

**Wearable Side**

```
public class DisconnectListenerService extends WearableListenerService implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {

/* the capability that the phone app would provide */
private static final String CONNECTION_STATUS_CAPABILITY_NAME = "is_connection_lost";

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .build();
}

@Override
public void onConnectedNodes(List<Node> connectedNodes) {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        updateStatus();
    } else if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}

private void updateStatus() {
    Wearable.CapabilityApi.getCapability(
            mGoogleApiClient, CONNECTION_STATUS_CAPABILITY_NAME,
            CapabilityApi.FILTER_REACHABLE).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<CapabilityApi.GetCapabilityResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(CapabilityApi.GetCapabilityResult result) {
                    if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                        updateConnectionCapability(result.getCapability());
                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to get capabilities, " + "status: " + result.getStatus().getStatusMessage());
                    }
                }
            });
}

private void updateConnectionCapability(CapabilityInfo capabilityInfo) {
    Set<Node> connectedNodes = capabilityInfo.getNodes();
    if (connectedNodes.isEmpty()) {
        // The connection is lost !
    } else {
        for (Node node : connectedNodes) {
            if (node.isNearby()) {
                // The connection is OK !
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    updateStatus();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() || mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

**Phone Side**

create a xml file in values/ directory named wear.xml

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="android_wear_capabilities">
        <item>is_connection_lost</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```