How test connection and disconection between Mobile App and Wear app
Currently i have a WearableService that implements onCapabilityChanged method that receive this events automatically (At least I think so) but i've been trying to fire it with emulators but it doesn't execute the method. Is necessary test with a real device?
I have a single service in my manifest (Currently i receive dataUpdates and messages without problems)

Check this link https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data/data-layer

Hi, currently i have connected my applications and configurated to be ables to listen between them, methods as onDataChanged and onMessageReceived works well but the method onCapabilityChanged (Thats has to be called automatically when connections and disconnections occurs) never is called

I got a solution for my issue following the next post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43357551/how-to-detect-when-android-wear-device-gets-disconnected?rq=3

I don't think you need to test it with a physical device, it should work with an emulator.
Have you already checked that your two applications share the same applicationId and were signed with the same key? That's a requirement to be able to use the Data Layer API.

Hello, yes all is right, currently I can send data updates and messages with my service. The only method that dont work is onCapabilityChanged. I have been trying to unpair devices with Android Studio option, turn off wifi, bluetooth etc. But the method does't get execute


Have you added the corresponding intent as described in point 2. of your link?

<intent-filter>
           <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.CAPABILITY_CHANGED" />
           <data android:scheme="wear" android:host="*"/>
</intent-filter>


what happens when you merely use the getCapability method? Do you manage to see the right devices?

capabilityClient
     .getCapability(capability, capabilityClient.FILTER_REACHABLE);


Or maybe try to use a simple Service instead of a WearableService as suggested here : OnCapabilityChanged working on phone but not on wearable

