# Wear OS listeners for entry/exit of devices from effective bluetooth range?

Tags: android, wear-os

I am developing an application to which some commands are delivered via watch to android phone using wear OS messaging mechanism.

When phone & watch are in range they get delivered correctly.

When they are not within range it says target not found exception which is correct behavior.

But when the phone comes within the range from out of range they ( Watch & Phone ) do not auto connect.

Are there any APIs in wear OS platform which provides listeners when a node exits/enters within range of devices?

In order to reconnect, Do we always need to scan nearby nodes?

Comment: Based from this [forum](https://www.reddit.com/r/Nexus6P/comments/3ri6lz/android_wear_doesnt_autoreconnect_after_coming/), you may fix it by turning off the battery optimization for the Android Wear app. You may also check this [tutorial](https://github.com/shiitakeo/android_wear_for_ios) on how to implement prototype of auto-reconnect.

Comment: Possible duplicate off https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25619190/detect-when-wearable-connected-disconnected-to-from-android-phone